# Mysql select table which depends on other two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three table `group`, `user` and `belongs` where `belongs` is relation between `group` and `user`.

```
Table group
group_id (pk)
group_name

Table user
user_id (pk)
user_name

Table belongs
user_id
group_id
```

I want to show a random groups that people in specified group are also in.
 
For example specified group is where group_id = 1, Of course, i can get people in this group by use

```
"SELECT user_id FROM user u JOIN belongs b ON u.user_id = b.user_id and b.group_id = '1'"
```

I have been trying, and now, i have no idea how to select group that these people are in too.

```
 "SELECT g.* FROM group g WHERE ..."
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of all the other groups associated with people in group 1 by using a sub-query:

```
SELECT g.group_name, COUNT(g.group_name)
FROM group g
INNER JOIN belongs b ON b.group_id = g.group_id
WHERE b.user_id IN ( SELECT u.user_id FROM user u JOIN belongs b ON u.user_id = b.user_id and b.group_id = '1' )
GROUP BY g.group_name
ORDER BY COUNT(g.group_name) DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, can i order them by count amount of these people in the group?

Comment: Updated to include sort by number of people in the associated groups.

Comment: It takes so long to query and i got this messages. `Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

Comment: How many records are in each table?  That query should be pretty quick.  Make sure you have indexes on your foreign keys.

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the groups by using an extra `join`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b2.group_id
FROM user u JOIN
     belongs b
     ON u.user_id = b.user_id and b.group_id = '1' JOIN
     belongs b2
     ON b2.user_id = b.user_id;
```

One way to choose a random such group is to use `order by rand() limit 1`.  You might want to add `where b2.group_id <> '1'`.

Assuming that you want to count the members of `group_id = 1` in these groups, you would just use `group by`:

```
SELECT b2.group_id, count(distinct b2.user_id) as numusers
FROM user u JOIN
     belongs b
     ON u.user_id = b.user_id and b.group_id = '1' JOIN
     belongs b2
     ON b2.user_id = b.user_id
GROUP BY b2.group_id;
```

The join to `user` is superfluous, but I have left it in assuming that it might be used for some other conditions not in the original question.

Comment: Thank you, and few more question, how can i order them by count amount of these people in the group?